# Magento isLoggedIn() always return false while customer is logged in

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, helper

I am new in `Magento`. Using `Magento 1.9.2` version i create `test.php` file in `Magento` root i which write the code

```
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
$customerName = Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn();
var_dump($customerName);exit;
```

It always returning me false while i have logged in one customer in new tab. I just want to get data current logged in customer. It giving me null please help me sort out that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use session for check is someone logged.

You can change 'name' to admin if you want check is someone logged into admin.
Solution found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723166/magento-can-not-detect-if-customer-is-logged-in-or-not

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';


umask(0);

Mage::app('default');

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo "Logged";
} else {
   echo "Not Logged";
}
```